# Python: Getting Keys and Values out of Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the following keys and values

```
tops = 
{'PEKISKO': 1011.0, 'DEIT': 992.2, 'MLKR': 348.0, 'MNVL': 891.2, 'CLRD': 449.3, 'SSPK': 667.0}
```

now I have a loop where I want to apply a function

```
for top, depth in tops.iteritems():
    topi = z.tolist().index(depth)
    toptwt = tp[topi] + ts[topi]
    tops['top'] = toptwt
```

what I want is the loop to create names for each key so that

```
PEKISKO = toptwt
DEIT = toptwt
```

so all keys in the dictionary will get names and values from the loop.

Comment: what do you mean `create names for each key` ? Can you show us what some values of toptwt would be and for those values are is your expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me OP is trying to create local or global variables out of the dictionary.  OP, why would you want to do that?  What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: i didn't understand what are you asking? can you explain your ouestion again?

Comment: Yes, what I was suggesting, and it's a bad idea... Because shadowing...

Comment: @AndyRoo - it appears that you want to replace the values in `tops` with the calculated value `toptwt`. Is that correct?

Comment: It's amazing that this question has **six comments** from baffled users who have no idea what this is asking, and **not one close vote** for "Unclear What You're Asking." Use the system, people!

Comment: I have a general rule: never attempt to modify the sequence you're iterating over. If you really need to do it, make a copy and iterate or modify the copy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intent, you need 2 fixes. First, you can't safely change a `dict` you are iterating. This is python 2.x code so use `items` instead of `iteritems` to make a list of item before you change anything. Second, use the variable `tops` not the string `"tops"` to update the `dict`.

```
for top, depth in tops.items():
    topi = z.tolist().index(depth)
    toptwt = tp[topi] + ts[topi]
    tops[top] = toptwt
```